# проверка строки на содержание букв

Tags: python, re

Я что-то туплю. Извините за заезжонность темы, я читал доки, но так и не понял свою ошибку.

Мне нужно проверит строку есть ли вообще в ней буквы.

```
import re

text1 = '127.0.0.1'
text2 = 'site-123.com'

regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+&"
pattern = re.compile(regex)

print(pattern.search(text1) is not None)
print(pattern.search(text2) is not None)
```

Желаю получить результат:
1 - False
2 - True

Но почему-то получаю оба False (моя ошибка явно в регулярке, но не пойму какая)

Comment: Я так понимаю, этот regex взят с другого вопроса здесь же? Слишком сложная регулярка, там были немного другие задачи. Если твоя задача `действительно` просто убедиться, что там есть хотя бы одна буква - хватит простого RegEx'а `"[A-Za-z]"`. И оно тебе выдаст если вдруг хоть где то встречается буква.

Comment: И еще, рекомендую потратить пол-часа и посмотреть на ютубе одно-два рандомный видео по RegExу.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 О вы правы, помогло, вот перемудрил)

Comment: Выражение `.-_` задаёт **диапазон** символов от точки (код 0x2e) до подчёркивания (код 0x5f), а вот дефис имеет код 0x2d и в этот диапазон не попадает. Если вы хотели задать не диапазон, а три отдельных символа, то, видимо, вы просто забыли экранировать дефис `.\-_`

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(text):
    for count, value in enumerate(text, start=0):
        if text[count].isalpha():
            return True
    return False

print(foo("28394832222"))
print(foo("283948иии22"))
```

Comment: 1) не добавляйте текстовые данные в виде скриншота. 2) `start=0` излишен